# Как отловить сообщении о перерисовке консоли?

Tags: консоль, visual-c++

Как отловить сообщении о перерисовке консоли?

Answer (score 1):

Думаю что ввод/вывод на консоль всегда происходит через стандартные потоки ввода и вывода. Каждый поток имеет в себе буффер. Не знаю как найти данные этого буфера но если найти то можно предположить так, можно периодически проверять данные буфера и следить за их изменениями. Если изменение произошло значит консоль перерисована.